# Where can I ask for better explanations?

Tags: discussion

So, If I get an answer, but I need more explanation to understand it.
Where can I ask for that explanation?
Take for example the answer here?
[What's the difference between convolution and crosscorrelation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353272/whats-the-difference-between-convolution-and-crosscorrelation)

Comment: Since there are no answers and the delete votes, does that imply that it is impossible to clarify the answer?

Answer (score 13):

Ask a follow-up question, link to the original question, and explain what you're still confused about.

Comment: @user68610: ask the followup question on the main site, as a new question, not as a comment. If you need clarification on a particular answer, comment on that answer.

Comment: Just a remark: When I just went through the review-queue for votes to close, [his follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378706/clarification-asked-for-difference-between-convolution-and-crosscorrelation) came up. Since it was "moderator-advised" to start a follow-up question, maybe something should be done to prevent the question gets closed? (It currently has 2 votes to close.)

Comment: @TMM Why do you vote for close in the first place? It has 2 votes up and no answers.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I'm deleting your comment and editing user68610's since the context is lost.

Comment: @user68610 Try to hang around a bit more before speculating about what other people are doing. I understand that you are new here and don't completely understand all the various mechanisms on this site. But TMM did not say anything about his or her "voting to close" your question. It was only indicated that TMM saw existing close votes.

Comment: For the record, I did *not* vote to close but voted to "leave open", whatever effect that may have on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I usally comment with "Thanks for your answer! can you please expend(/add) your explanation for why XYZ"

Comment: And if they don't appreciate a response like that?

Comment: @user68610 - If you post a question and someone answer it is probably the case that they want you to understand their solutions. this way of asking for more information is not rude and I never encountered someone who answered me and didn't respond nicely

Comment: @user68610 I think they will prefer it to you asking them first to starting a thread like this...